# Type not found in context, possible mapping issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use the `EntityFramework.BulkInsert` extension but I keep getting an exception of `Type 'MyEntity.CallDetail' is not found in context 'MyEntity.MyEntities'`. I tracked this exception to the `DBMapping` class in the `EntityFramework.MappingAPI`. The method that throws it is :

```
    public IEntityMap this[string typeFullName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_tableMappings.ContainsKey(typeFullName))
                throw new Exception("Type '" + typeFullName + "' is not found in context '" + _contextTypeName + "'");

            return _tableMappings[typeFullName];
        }
    }
```

My question is, is this an error in the `EntityFramework.MappingAPI` or this this something in my code?

My context class:

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities()
        : base("name=MyEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<CallDetail> CallDetail { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PhoneState> PhoneStates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<StateLog> StateLogs { get; set; }
}
```

I'm assuming that the error is caused by everything being `DBSet<...>` instead of just the type but I may be wrong.

If it is in my code (which is most probable) what do I need to do to make this work?

EDIT: Thanks to @BenRobinson, the issue is due to the EF mapping. I have been able to find that others have been having similar issues with `EntityFramework.MappingAPI` on DB first models as found [here](http://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/workitem/1383), [here](http://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/workitem/1414), and [here](http://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/workitem/1464). Since I am new to EF, I'm hoping that someone can see an issue in the `edmx` that could be causing the problem. Below is the info from the edmx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <!-- EF Runtime content -->
    <edmx:Runtime>
        <!-- SSDL content -->
        <edmx:StorageModels>
            <Schema Namespace="my_contactModel.Store" Provider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="5.6" Alias="Self" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
                <EntityType Name="call_detail">
                    ....
                </EntityType>
                <EntityContainer Name="my_contactModelStoreContainer">
                    <EntitySet Name="call_detail" EntityType="Self.call_detail" Schema="my_contact" store:Type="Tables" />
                    ....
                </EntityContainer>
            </Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
        <!-- CSDL content -->
        <edmx:ConceptualModels>
            <Schema Namespace="MyContactModel" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
                <EntityType Name="CallDetail">
                    ....
                </EntityType>
                <EntityContainer Name="MyEntities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
                    <EntitySet Name="CallDetail" EntityType="MyContactModel.CallDetail" />
                    ....
                </EntityContainer>
            </Schema>
        </edmx:ConceptualModels>
        <!-- C-S mapping content -->
        <edmx:Mappings>
            <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
                <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="my_contactModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="MyEntities">
                    <EntitySetMapping Name="CallDetail">
                        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MyContactModel.CallDetail">
                            <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="call_detail">
                                ....
                            </MappingFragment>
                        </EntityTypeMapping>
                    </EntitySetMapping>
                </EntityContainerMapping>
            </Mapping>
        </edmx:Mappings>
    </edmx:Runtime>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Its almost certainly your code as EF works. You haven't shown any of your mapping code, how are you mapping your entities? Fluent api or attributes?

Comment: @BenRobinson I'm relatively new when it comes to EF, I have not changed any mappings from what the EF wizard generated. Do I need to map the tables in addition to what the wizard did?

Comment: Are you using code first or database first with an edmx file?

Comment: Database first with the generated edmx

Comment: @BenRobinson I added the relative part of the generated edmx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was having this same issue, and was able to resolve it simply by updating my EntityFramework.MappingAPI !  [NuGet MappingAPI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.MappingAPI) . After updating, I simply rebuilt my project and no longer had the exception.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me and couldn't find this answer anywhere else.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like BulkInsert should require a more recent version of MappingAPI

Answer (score 6):

This exact error and proposed solution worked for me.  After installation of the EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6 package, go back to Manage NuGet Packages and there should be an Update for EntityFramework.MappingAPI.  After updating, run your context.BulkInsert(listOfObjects); line and it should succeed.

Answer (score 1):

The EntityFramework.MappingAPI and EntityFramework.BulkInsert-EFx are not obsolte. The Z.EntityFramework.Extensions packe should be used.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.entityframework.extensions

The syntax is a little different now (e.g. `db.BulkInsert(addresses, bulk => bulk.InsertKeepIdentity = true);`) but it works great for me.